# IOS: Change image bar button in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the bar button item with an image into another bar button, which contain different image and do different function. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this in your code block:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage.png"];// set your image Name 
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bImage.size.width, bImage.size.height);
        UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

        self.navigationItem.barButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: It works great, thanks for the help. I need to navigate to another UIViewController by clicking the added button, can you help me with that?

Comment: use [barbtn addTarget:self action@selector(methotSwitch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ,it is custom view of the image bar button in navigation bar

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mail-48_24.png"];
    CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height);
    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendmail)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
    [someButton release];
```

Answer (score 0):

set original image and on pressed the button go to the target method set another image and repeat this according to barbutton text..